# How do I access the props from my React Dropzone component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, dropzone.js, dropzone

my project involves dragging some photo's onto my react app and being able to upload them.

I've created a photo state that will hold the photo when uploaded:

```
const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);
```

> **My dropzone component looks like this:**

```
<div className="listItem__right__window__formWrapper">
                    <label className="listItem__right__window__inputLabel" htmlFor="">Upload Photo's:</label>
                    <Dropzone
                        className="dropzone"
                        autoUpload={false}
                        getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
                        onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                        accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"
                        inputContent={(photo, extra) => (extra.reject ? 'Only Image, audio and video files allowed!' : 'Select and Drop Files')}
                        styles={{
                            dropzoneReject: { borderColor: '#F19373', backgroundColor: '#F1BDAB' },
                            inputLabel: (photo, extra) => (extra.reject ? { color: '#A02800' } : {}),
                        }}
                    />
                    <span className="listItem__right__window__nextIcon" onClick={clickNext}>
                        <KeyboardReturnIcon />
                        <h4>Press Enter To Advance</h4>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

***So my thinking was:***

> When something changes within my dropzone component, i'll call
> setPhoto and store the files currently uploaded, like this:

```
// Return the current status of files being uploaded
const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, file }, status) => {
    setPhoto(this.props.files); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
}
```

**Sadly this doesn't work ^^^**

I can see the files are stored like so:

[image]

Can anybody help me out with an efficient way to access the files in the dropzones props so I have control of them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [react-dropzone-uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Per the [documentation](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start), you can use the `onSubmit` prop to pass a function that will receive the array of files that are done uploading when the submit button is clicked:

```js
  // receives array of files that are done uploading when submit button is clicked
  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
    allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"
    />
```